# JS Array Reduce with Merging Duplicate Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "name": "walkway_lights",
        "title": "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight",
        "subCat": "Area & Pathway Lights",
        "cat": "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
        "msrp": 599,
        "accTotal": 50,
        "purchasePrice": 222.35,
        "totalPrice": 1222,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 468.7,
        "lightShadowColor": "warmWhite",
        "wattage": {
            "key": "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK",
            "upPrice": 12,
            "value": "3.5w G4"
        },
        "selectedAccessory": [
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S",
                "name": "Demo 1",
                "price": 5
            },
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU",
                "name": "Demo 2",
                "price": 10
            },
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9Vh4yBK9j-GNpA0v",
                "name": "Demo 4",
                "price": 20
            }
        ],
        "beam": {
            "key": "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw",
            "value": "360"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "walkway_lights",
        "title": "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight",
        "type": "group",
        "subCat": "Area & Pathway Lights",
        "cat": "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
        "msrp": 599,
        "accTotal": 15,
        "purchasePrice": 222.35,
        "totalPrice": 626,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 249.35,
        "lightShadowColor": "warmWhite",
        "wattage": {
            "key": "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK",
            "upPrice": 12,
            "value": "3.5w G4"
        },
        "selectedAccessory": [
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S",
                "name": "Demo 1",
                "price": 5
            },
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU",
                "name": "Demo 2",
                "price": 10
            },
            ,
            {
                "key": "-Mxa9ZUjMExUd3g5Ugfs",
                "name": "Demo 3",
                "price": 15
            }
        ],
        "beam": {
            "key": "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw",
            "value": "360"
        }
    }
]
```

I need to reformat "myArray" in such a way that it nest all objects based "subCat" and then "subCat" inside "cat". In those nested children, I am converting duplicate objects based on "name + lightShadowColor + wattage.value + beam.value" and I am adding a variable "count" to remove duplicate objects. I am able to come up with a solution like below:

```
let result = [], counter = {};
for (let item of myArray) {
    let countId;
    if(item.lightShadowColor && item.wattage) {
    countId = item.name + item.lightShadowColor + item.wattage.value + item.beam.value
    } else {
    countId = item.name
    }
    let a = [];
    if (counter[countId]) {
    counter[countId].count++;
    counter[countId].totalPrice = counter[countId].count * (counter[countId].msrp + counter[countId].wattage.upPrice)
    counter[countId].totalPurchasePrice = counter[countId].count * (counter[countId].purchasePrice + counter[countId].wattage.upPrice);
    continue
    }

    let cat = result.find(o => o.cat == item.cat);
    if (!cat) result.push(cat = { cat: item.cat, children: [] });
    let subCat = cat.children.find(o => o.subCat == item.subCat);
    if (!subCat) cat.children.push(subCat = { subCat: item.subCat, children: [] });
    item.count = 1;
    subCat.children.push(counter[countId] = item);
}
console.log(result)
```

The above code gives me output which I desire as below:

```
result = [
    {
        "cat": "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
        "children": [
            {
                "subCat": "Area & Pathway Lights",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "count": 2
                        "name": "walkway_lights",
                        "title": "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight",
                        "subCat": "Area & Pathway Lights",
                        "cat": "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
                        "msrp": 599,
                        "accTotal": 50,
                        "purchasePrice": 222.35,
                        "totalPrice": 1222,
                        "totalPurchasePrice": 468.7,
                        "lightShadowColor": "warmWhite",
                        "wattage": {
                            "key": "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK",
                            "upPrice": 12,
                            "value": "3.5w G4"
                        },
                        "selectedAccessory": [
                            {
                                "key": "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S",
                                "name": "Demo 1",
                                "price": 5
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU",
                                "name": "Demo 2",
                                "price": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "-Mxa9Vh4yBK9j-GNpA0v",
                                "name": "Demo 4",
                                "price": 20
                            }
                        ],
                        "beam": {
                            "key": "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw",
                            "value": "360"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, I am trying to figure out how should I merge "selectedAccessory" array for duplicate objects. Any idea how should I merge those keys? Inside the result, I need "selectedAccessory" array like this:

```
"selectedAccessory": [
    //The below come from myArray first duplicate object
    {
        "key": "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S",
        "name": "Demo 1",
        "price": 5
    },
    {
        "key": "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU",
        "name": "Demo 2",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "key": "-Mxa9Vh4yBK9j-GNpA0v",
        "name": "Demo 4",
        "price": 20
    },
    //The below come from myArray second duplicate object
    {     
        "key": "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S",
        "name": "Demo 1",
        "price": 5
    },
    {
        "key": "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU",
        "name": "Demo 2",
        "price": 10
    },
    ,
    {
        "key": "-Mxa9ZUjMExUd3g5Ugfs",
        "name": "Demo 3",
        "price": 15
    }
],
```

Comment: what result do you expect for the last grouping?

Comment: 1. I want to combine “selectedAccessory” array 2. If possible add a count key as well inside for duplicate accessories. In this example, we have “Demo 1” and “Demo 2” is occurring 2 times inside combination so i would like to add count:2 inside Demo 1 and Demo 2 objects.

Comment: do you want to add price propety or get an array of prices?

Comment: Yes i do. I want price added as i have in my code but also want to merge arrays of “selectedAccessory” property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly, this should work.
Now when we see the same `countId`, we check the `selectedAccessory`. If there is an object with already existing `key` and `name`, we increment its count.
By default if the count is 1, we don't add it.

Please ask if needed.

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    name: "walkway_lights",
    title: "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight",
    subCat: "Area & Pathway Lights",
    cat: "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
    msrp: 599,
    accTotal: 50,
    purchasePrice: 222.35,
    totalPrice: 1222,
    totalPurchasePrice: 468.7,
    lightShadowColor: "warmWhite",
    wattage: { key: "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK", upPrice: 12, value: "3.5w G4", },
    selectedAccessory: [ { key: "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S", name: "Demo 1", price: 5, }, { key: "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU", name: "Demo 2", price: 10, }, { key: "-Mxa9Vh4yBK9j-GNpA0v", name: "Demo 4", price: 20, }, ],
    beam: { key: "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw", value: "360", },
  },
  {
    name: "walkway_lights",
    title: "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight",
    type: "group",
    subCat: "Area & Pathway Lights",
    cat: "Fixture-Speaker-Sub",
    msrp: 599,
    accTotal: 15,
    purchasePrice: 222.35,
    totalPrice: 626,
    totalPurchasePrice: 249.35,
    lightShadowColor: "warmWhite",
    wattage: { key: "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK", upPrice: 12, value: "3.5w G4", },
    selectedAccessory: [ { key: "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S", name: "Demo 1", price: 5, }, { key: "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU", name: "Demo 2", price: 10, }, { key: "-Mxa9ZUjMExUd3g5Ugfs", name: "Demo 3", price: 15, }, ],
    beam: { key: "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw", value: "360", },
  },
];

const result = [];

const findSameType = (item, array) => {
  return array.find(el => {
    if (item.name !== el.name) {
      return false;
    }
    if (item.lightShadowColor && item.wattage) {
      return item.lightShadowColor === el.lightShadowColor
        && item.wattage.value === el.wattage.value
        && item.beam.value === el.beam.value;
    }
    return true;
  })
}
  
for (let item of myArray) {
  let cat = result.find((o) => o.cat === item.cat)
  if (!cat) {
    cat = { cat: item.cat, children: [] };
    result.push(cat);
  }

  let subCat = cat.children.find((o) => o.subCat === item.subCat);
  if (!subCat) {
    subCat = { subCat: item.subCat, children: [] };
    cat.children.push(subCat);
  }
  const same = findSameType(item, subCat.children)

  if (same) {
    same.count++;
    same.totalPrice = same.count * (same.msrp + same.wattage.upPrice);
    same.totalPurchasePrice = same.count * (same.purchasePrice + same.wattage.upPrice);
    item.selectedAccessory.forEach(isa => {
      const same2 = same.selectedAccessory.find(csa => csa.key === isa.key && csa.name === isa.name);
      if (same2) {
        same2.count = same2.count ? (same2.count + 1) : 2;
      } else {
        same.selectedAccessory.push({...isa});
      }
    })
  } else {
    item.count = 1;
    subCat.children.push({
      ...item,
      selectedAccessory: item.selectedAccessory.map(sa => ({ ...sa }))
    });
  }
}

console.log('result', result);
console.log('myArray', myArray)
```

Comment: Also try to do console.log(myArray) in the end. It messes up the original myArray "SelectedAccessory" list.

Comment: Can you please check? I want to keep my original myArray as is and does not want to mutate that.

Comment: @KartikSolanki try this solution

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach for a multi level grouping with an object which keeps the reference to the nested array by using a key to address the group.

Tha main advantage is to use a simplified data structure for getting a single level and take a function to update the level as desired.

The given data has to evels to group and another array which need the same reference for gouping, because of the samegroup and multiple objects of `selectedAccessory`. This data is grouped as well and all prices are stored in an array. it could be any other data type as well.

The usage is pretty simple. for only grouping, it take a simple function which gets a single object from data array anf separates a `key` and returns an object with `key`, which is self explaining, a data object with wanted properties, a property `children` which has the property name of the array which helds the nested levels and a `rest` property, which has the rest of the object with unused parts of this level.

As an option, it could have an `update` propert which is for updating the actual level object with further information and calculation.

Here an example:

```
({ cat, ...rest }) => ({ key: cat, data: { cat }, children: 'children', rest })
```

This is the first grouping function which take `cat` from the object and takes the rest of the object in `rest`. It return

- the `key` with the value of `cat`,
- an object `data`, which reflects the level object,
- the name of the children array for the next level and
- the rest of the object.

For an example of an update propert/function have a look below.

```js
const
    groupBy = (data, levels, references = { __: [] }) => data
        .reduce((r, o, i) => {
            levels
                .reduce((q, fn, j) => {
                    const { key, data, children, rest, update } = fn(o, q, i, j);

                    if (key === undefined) {
                        q.__.push(data);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!q[key]) {
                        q[key] = { __: [] };
                        q.__.push(q[key]._ = children
                            ? { ...data, [children]: q[key].__ }
                            : data
                        );
                    }

                    update?.(o, q[key]._, q[key]);
                    o = rest;
                    return q[key];
                }, r);
            return r;
        }, references)
        .__,
    data = [{ name: "walkway_lights", title: "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight", subCat: "Area & Pathway Lights", cat: "Fixture-Speaker-Sub", msrp: 599, accTotal: 50, purchasePrice: 222.35, totalPrice: 1222, totalPurchasePrice: 468.7, lightShadowColor: "warmWhite", wattage: { key: "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK", upPrice: 12, value: "3.5w G4" }, selectedAccessory: [{ key: "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S", name: "Demo 1", price: 5 }, { key: "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU", name: "Demo 2", price: 10 }, { key: "-Mxa9Vh4yBK9j-GNpA0v", name: "Demo 4", price: 20 }], beam: { key: "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw", value: "360" } }, { name: "walkway_lights", title: "Brilliance Sequoia Pathlight", type: "group", subCat: "Area & Pathway Lights", cat: "Fixture-Speaker-Sub", msrp: 599, accTotal: 15, purchasePrice: 222.35, totalPrice: 626, totalPurchasePrice: 249.35, lightShadowColor: "warmWhite", wattage: { key: "-Mm46mr5KHJwLXsucsJK", upPrice: 12, value: "3.5w G4" }, selectedAccessory: [{ key: "-Mxa9Jt-9si0Bw7Zhj1S", name: "Demo 1", price: 5 }, { key: "-Mxa9NUjMExUd8b5UgfU", name: "Demo 2", price: 10 }, { key: "-Mxa9ZUjMExUd3g5Ugfs", name: "Demo 3", price: 15 }], beam: { key: "-Mm4B0FO34Ineht5O0sw", value: "360" } }],
    levels = [
        ({ cat, ...rest }) => ({ key: cat, data: { cat }, children: 'children', rest }),
        ({ subCat, ...rest }) => ({ key: subCat, data: { subCat }, children: 'children', rest }),
        ({ name, msrp, accTotal, purchasePrice, totalPrice, totalPurchasePrice, lightShadowColor, wattage, selectedAccessory, beam, ...rest }) => ({
            key: lightShadowColor && wattage ? [name, lightShadowColor, wattage.value, beam.value].join('|') : name,
            data: { name, msrp, accTotal, purchasePrice, totalPrice, totalPurchasePrice, count: 0, lightShadowColor, wattage },
            children: 'selectedAccessory',
            update: (source, target, reference) => {
                target.count++;
                target.totalPrice = target.count * (target.msrp + target.wattage.upPrice);
                target.totalPurchasePrice = target.count * (target.purchasePrice + target.wattage.upPrice);
                groupBy(selectedAccessory, [
                    ({key, name, ...rest }) => ({ key, data: { key, name }, children: 'price', rest }),
                    ({ price }) => ({ data: price })
                ], reference);
            },
            rest
        })
    ],
    result = groupBy(data, levels);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```